# How to access mysql pod in another pod(busybox)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am given a task of connecting mysql pod with any other working pod(preferably busybox) but was not able to that. Is there a way to do this task. I referred many places but the explanations was bit complicated as I am new to Kubernetes.

Comment: we would appreciate if you could elaborate `"but was not able to that."`, what have you tried already. Also, when you say `access/connecting` what does you really mean? (Eg: `exec` , `REST`, `kubectl` ??)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL YAML config for Kubernets

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

you can use the service name to connect with the MySQL from busy box container

```
kubectl run -i --tty mysql-client --image=mysql --restart=Never -- sh
```

above command will start one container of **Mysql** as client.

run `kubectl get pods` to check both pod status.

In Mysql-client container you will be able to run the command to connect with the MySQL

```
mysql -h <MySQL service name> -u <Username> -p<password>
```

Ref doc : MySQL : https://kubernetes.io/blog/2015/10/some-things-you-didnt-know-about-kubectl_28/

Comment: When i run mysql cmd in the busy box its throwing this error "sh: mysql: not found" should i use some other image instead of busybox?

Comment: you can use the other image or install the MySQL client into busy box image, hope you know command to install the mysq client. consider busy box as ubuntu system one sh is open you can use and install the CLI apt-get install myql.....client or whatever command is tehre

Comment: I tried to install in busybox but could not succeed instead i used ubuntu image followed the steps u mentioned. At last It got executed.The answer was really helpful. Cheers!

Comment: glad to hear that issue resolved. you can also upvote the answer, if found it helpful.

Comment: MySQL is not part of busybox, so the answer is not correct

Comment: instead busybox used MySQL that has by defalt option mysql can we can use it as the client pod also.